# How to alter symbols on Piper Plot using package hydrogeo by category in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, graphics, package, symbols

I am using the package 'hydrogeo' https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydrogeo/hydrogeo.pdf to create piper plot diagrams from a data frame of ~4000 entries.

How can I assign symbols/colours to each entry according to category or type? The usual R commands for editing graphical parameters don't appear to apply as I get the following error when trying to standardize symbols using -

`pch = OR col=`

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : formal argument "pch" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest assigning `pch`, `col` in your main data frame or `tibble` by first extracting your sites;

```
PlaceHolders = as.tibble(unique(df$Sites))
```

Then generating `pch` and `col` using a rep statement and color palette;

```
PlaceHolders$pch = rep(c(15:18),length.out = length(unique(factor(df$Sites))))
```

and

```
PlaceHolders$col = rainbow(n = length(unique(factor(df$Sites))))
```

I would add the units in to ensure you do not forget what they are:

```
PlaceHolders$units = rep("mg/l",dim(PlaceHolders)[1])
```

Now you only need to do a left_join with your main data set by = "Sites" and you should be good to go.